# How to specify IP to use in gitlab-ci file?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, cypress

I've got test job called "e2e" to run in my project but when it reaches the point to execute the test it throws:

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
  > http://nginx
We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:19.03.5-dind

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1


compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip python2-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make npm
    - pip install docker-compose
    - npm install randomstring --save-dev
    - docker-compose up -d --build
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py recreate_db
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py test
    - docker-compose exec -T client npm test -- --coverage --watchAll --watchAll=false


e2e:
  stage: test
  image: cypress/base:10
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run runHeadless
```

I specified `http://nginx` as a baseUrl in cypress.json because that's how it suppose to
work in production. I changed it to `http://127.0.0.1` for development but that didn't help.

I suspect it's because I'm not specifying network to use in `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Am I correct ?